# WebSocket. How connect and custom ID

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, adonis.js

WebSocket generates a unique id. I need custom it (Send it by front-end or change in backend. whatever),

How to do this?

Or, How to receive stocke.id in my front

Code front in angular

```
import Ws from '@adonisjs/websocket-client';

this.socket = Ws(wsUrl, {});
this.connection = this.socket.connect(); // ------> what's the id? <------
this.chat = this.socket.subscribe('chat');
```

Code Back-end nodejs adonisjs

```
constructor({ socket, request }) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.request = request;
    console.log(socket.id) //ID to return
}
```

Comment: You mention socket.io, but then your code shows the Ws library which is not socket.io.  Which is it?  Socket.io automatically creates a unique id for each connection and is available as `socket.id`.  I don't see any evidence that the Ws library creates a unique id for you so if that's what you're using, you would have to create your id on the server and send it to the client so the client could store it.

Answer (score 0):

For example, using a small Websocket Wrapper Library called `Sockette`
https://github.com/lukeed/sockette

Usually, a Websocket is a 2-Way Communication Channel. You can receive and send messages to a `wss://` Endpoint.

The onmessage Handler will receive any message, the Server sends you (for example, an ID)

```js
const Sockette = require('sockette');

const ws = new Sockette('ws://localhost:3000', {
  timeout: 5e3,
  maxAttempts: 10,
  onopen: e => console.log('Connected!', e),
  onmessage: e => console.log('Received:', e),
  onreconnect: e => console.log('Reconnecting...', e),
  onmaximum: e => console.log('Stop Attempting!', e),
  onclose: e => console.log('Closed!', e),
  onerror: e => console.log('Error:', e)
});
```